# Execute Java program server-side from a Node.js / Heroku app?

Tags: java, node.js, heroku

Can I call a Java program from a Node.js application on Heroku?

I have a Node.js/Heroku app.  But now need to add server-side capability to run an algorithm on an input data file and output data to a JSON format.  I already have a Java library that can read the file and run the algorithm, and it would be very difficult (at best) for me to re-write it in pure Node.js.

So, could write a command line program, that takes an input file and pipes the results to stdout, e.g.

`java mytask.class -cp ./mylibrary.jar --in /tmp/file.in > output.json`

Is it possible to shell out a call to a Java command line program from Node.js?   I know one can deploy Java applications to Heroku, but here want to execute a bit of Java from a Node.js app.

Comment: May be less fragile to add a web service over the existing Java code and call that from node.js

Comment: Aha, excellent point, even if it were native Node.js it would be good to separate that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you want [this](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and `child_process.exec()` in particular ?

> Node provides a tri-directional popen(3) facility through the
>   child_process module.
>
> It is possible to stream data through a child's stdin, stdout, and
>   stderr in a fully non-blocking way.

Note that your example command above isn't right, since you're trying to pipe to a file (`output.json`). Pipes only work between processes. The child process module would allow you to read the processes' stdout directly and you wouldn't need the file (similarly for the input stream)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!  Yes, calling child_process.exec() is ideal, and piping straight back even better.   My uncertainty is whether java VM is installed, and if it can run a class/library I provide?

Comment: @user645715 I haven't checked, but I don't think a Java runtime is installed when node.js applications are installed. You'd either have to make you java app a stand-alone executable, push the Java runtime with your app or for and modify the [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) to include a Java runtime.

Comment: Long delayed followup, Java appears installed by default in Heroku Cedar stack, and calling via shell worked very well.